# Instance of Bounded for Double in Haskell

Tags: haskell

[Prelude](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#t:Bounded) does not provide a Bounded Double instance. Is this because Double does not have a min/max argument in Haskell (that Bounded requires) or is the reason different?

Comment: what do you mean with a `min`/`max` argument?

Comment: The minimum and maximum values of a `Double` would be `-Infinity` and `Infinity`, but these are not really actual (numerical) values, I think that is the reationale. It would mean that `[minBound .. maxBound]` would yield `[-Infinity, -Infinity, ...]` which is probably not the expected result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that `maxBound > x` should hold true for any other `x :: Bounded a => a`, what should the value of `maxBound :: Double` be?

```
> let nan = 0/0; infinity = 10.0**10000; in (nan > infinity, infinity > nan)
(False,False)
```

The *numbers* represented by `Double` are bounded, but the values in the type `Double` are not.

Comment: I think you meant `>=` and `10.0**10000`.

Comment: `>` was intentional; I'm assuming the bounds should be unique (though I'm flexible on that point).

Comment: The Haskell 98 report explicitly says Bounded types need not be totally ordered (Double won't be, since there's a NaN value). RealFloat allows finding the highest and lowest numbers available, but the infinities aren't numbers, so what the bounds should be might be arguable.